# How to change "filebrowserBrowseUrl" and "filebrowserImageUploadUrl" in CKFinder using Java

Tags: java, ckeditor, ckfinder

I am trying to integrate CKEditor-3.5.x with CKFinder-2.2 in a Java web application built on Spring 3 framework and everything seems to work alright except the "Send it to the Server" button when I try to upload an image/flash file to the server.

I get the following error when I try to do that:

> No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/myapp/ckfinder/core/connector/java/connector.java] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'

I need `/myapp/resources/ckfinder/core/connector/java/connector.java` HTTP request to be mapped instead.

How could I get it done?

Answer (score 0):

In case someone comes aross the same issue, adding the the following got things working for me:

**.jsp file that needs the text area to be integrated with ckeditor and ckfinder**

```
<%@ page import="com.ckeditor.CKEditorConfig" %>
<% 
    CKEditorConfig settings = new CKEditorConfig();
    settings.addConfigValue("filebrowserBrowseUrl","/myapp/resources/ckfinder/ckfinder.html");
    settings.addConfigValue("filebrowserImageBrowseUrl","/myapp/resources/ckfinder/ckfinder.html?type=Images");
    settings.addConfigValue("filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl","/myapp/resources/ckfinder/ckfinder.html?type=Flash");
    settings.addConfigValue("filebrowserUploadUrl","/myapp/resources/ckfinder/core/connector/java/connector.java?command=QuickUpload&type=Files");
    settings.addConfigValue("filebrowserImageUploadUrl","/myapp/resources/ckfinder/core/connector/java/connector.java?command=QuickUpload&type=Images");
    settings.addConfigValue("filebrowserFlashUploadUrl","/myapp/resources/ckfinder/core/connector/java/connector.java?command=QuickUpload&type=Flash");
%>

<ckeditor:replace replace="editor1" basePath="/myapp/resources/ckeditor/" config="<%=settings %>" />
```